# Using a switch to sort information from File (C)

Tags: c, file-io, switch-statement

So I'm getting an infinite loop when running the code with the switch statement, but not when I have it commented out, so I know the problem lies within. Basically, I have to take a list of a char and float from a file like:

```
S 15.42
G 28.00
S 56.50
H 90.00
H 10.40
S 67.90
0
```

I need to sort and add the totals according to each of the char's corresponding organizations (s= salvation army, etc.) Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


float amount,goodTotal,habTotal,salTotal,totalTotal;
char org[1],S,H,G;
FILE *input, *output;
input = fopen("input.txt","r");
output = fopen("output.txt","w");

if (input == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file input!\n");
    exit(1);
}

    while(fscanf(input, "%c %f", org, &amount)!=EOF){

        switch (org){
            case 'S':
                salTotal += amount;
                break;
            case 'H':
                habTotal += amount;
                break;
            case 'G':
                goodTotal += amount;
                break;

        }

    fprintf(output,"Charity     Number of Donations     Total Donation   \n");
    fprintf(output,"-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(output,"Goodwill             num            $%f\n",goodTotal);
    fprintf(output,"Habitat for Humanity num            $%f\n",habTotal);
    fprintf(output,"Salvation Army       num            $%f\n",salTotal);
    fprintf(output,"-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(output,"Total                num            $%f\n",totalTotal);
    }


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, the text "num" in the last few lines are placeholders for the number of each "donation" - I just haven't gotten around to writing the code out.

Comment: How do you know you're getting an infinite loop?

Comment: Perhaps I am incorrect but I'm getting an error message when compiling and running it through Windows itself.

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: You know what, I have no idea. I can't make it get the error message anymore and everything seems to be working now (?!?)...

Comment: @immibis: Seems to be working except for it counting the last line under the previous one's. For example, it's adding the last "0" in the total count of # of donations as another donation - under the Salvation Army. (I should be getting 6 total, 3 coming from SalArmy, but I'm getting 7 and 4 respectively)

Comment: Don't edit question title to mark it as answered. If some answer helps you, mark it as accepted, or you may add your own answer if needed

Comment: I'm sorry. I was unsure of how to mark it answered! @LưuVĩnhPhúc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
while(fscanf(input, "%c %f", org, &amount)!=EOF)
```

With

```
while(fscanf(input, "%c %f", org, &amount)== 2)
{
    fgetc(input);           //Consume New line char
```

`fscanf` returns the number of inputs scanned.

And as others pointed out correctly

use `switch (org[0]){`

Comment: Still getting the infinite loop after trying that.

Comment: @StephenRosedale I have edited the answer,this will solve your problem.

Comment: Seems to be working except for it counting the last line under the previous one's. For example, it's adding the last "0" in the total count of # of donations as another donation - under the Salvation Army. (I should be getting 6 total, 3 coming from SalArmy, but I'm getting 7 and 4 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
    switch (org){
```

with

```
    switch (org[0]){
```

or better yet, make `org` a `char` and use

```
fscanf(input, "%c %f", &org, &amount)
```

Comment: This seems to only affect the first line from my input file but none of the subsequent ones.